# Match specific lines in sed command

Tags: unix, text, command-line, sed, pipe

How can I match a set of specific lines for a substitution command?

(incorrect):

```
sed -e'71,116,211s/[ ]+$//' ...
```

I want to strip trailing whitespace on lines 71, 116 and 211 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
awk 'NR== 71 || NR == 116 || NR == 211 {sub(/ *$/,"",$0)}{print $0}'
```

or

```
sed '71s/ *$//;116s///;211s///'
```

Comment: I thought of posting your `sed` solution but with a small improvement (I think), if you leave the regex part blank, it takes the last one. So only neccesary to write it once (for first line) and later like: `... 116s///;...`

Comment: good point - i'd forgotten about that - I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '71bl;116bl;211bl;b;:l;s/[ ][ ]*$//' input
```

For any specified line, this script jumps to the label `l`. Other lines will jump to the end of the script with the bare `branch`.

And an awk solution:

```
awk -v k="71,116,221" 'BEGIN{split(k,a,",")} 
            (NR in a) { sub(/ *$/,"",$0) }1' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\s+$/!b;71s///;116s///;221s///' file
```

or perhaps:

```
sed -e '/  *$/!b' -e '71s///' -e '116s///' -e '221s///' file
```

or as has been said already:

```
sed -e '71ba' -e '116ba' -e '221ba' -e 'b' -e ':a' -e 's/  *$//' file
```